# Bulk editing Kubernetes annotations with Kustomize without pods restarting

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

I am trying to find the best way to bulk edit the annotations on a number of Kubernetes resources. It seems like Kustomize might be the best option:

1. The resources are already part of kustomization.yaml
2. I can then edit kustomization.yaml with my new or revised annotation
3. `kubectl apply -k ./` updates all the relevant resources with the new annotation as desired

Unfortunately this makes all the pods terminate and restart, which is sometimes more lengthy than I'd hoped. Applying an annotation without Kustomize, when there are no other changes to the YAML, does not require redeployments and I'd love to do something similar, but in bulk. Any tips are appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

It seems your pods are managed by some replica-set(deployment, daemonset, statefulset etc) and rightly so. Updating these will result in updated pod spec and hence the redeployments.

You can look at `kubectl annotate` command.

Some examples from `kubectl annotate --help`

```
Examples:
  # Update pod 'foo' with the annotation 'description' and the value 'my frontend'.
  # If the same annotation is set multiple times, only the last value will be applied
  kubectl annotate pods foo description='my frontend'

  # Update a pod identified by type and name in "pod.json"
  kubectl annotate -f pod.json description='my frontend'

  # Update pod 'foo' with the annotation 'description' and the value 'my frontend running nginx', overwriting any
existing value.
  kubectl annotate --overwrite pods foo description='my frontend running nginx'

  # Update all pods in the namespace
  kubectl annotate pods --all description='my frontend running nginx'

  # Update pod 'foo' only if the resource is unchanged from version 1.
  kubectl annotate pods foo description='my frontend running nginx' --resource-version=1

  # Update pod 'foo' by removing an annotation named 'description' if it exists.
  # Does not require the --overwrite flag.
  kubectl annotate pods foo description-
```

Comment: Yes, using statefulsets mostly. I originally was using `kubectl annotate`, and both it and `kubectl apply` (after editing YAML) are nice because they don't require re-deploys for labels & annotations. But `kubectl annotate` doesn't change the underlying YAMLs, and editing the YAMLs manually and then doing `kubectl apply` is too manual & time-consuming.

Comment: I mean you can do the following
1. `kubectl annotate` on running pods
2. pause the rollouts of your statefulesets until you don't need redeployments using `kubectl rollout pause`
3. Use kustomize to update/create/apply your new YAMLs. As you have paused the rollout in prev step, no redeployment would happen
4. Resume the rollout `kubectl rollout resume` when you are ready for redeployments